# Root Cannot Open a PDF Ubuntu while users can

Tags: linux, pdf

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I tried to open a pdf using evince.

It worked well when I'm logged in the normal user but not when I'm using sudo or switch to root user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the permission to access the display server.

Generally, depending on your setup, you may need to [allow root to access the xserver](https://askubuntu.com/a/175615/668478). https://askubuntu.com/a/175615/668478

If you run on mir, you should [use gksudo to allow root to access mir](https://askubuntu.com/a/817906/668478).